# show selected value from grid view row using check box asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

is there something wrong in my code? i want to show the value of row 8 in my gridview. i have this code and its not working out for me. No errors but it does not show the value i am expecting to see.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = string.Empty;
        string strname = string.Empty;
        foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chkRow");
            if (chk != null & chk.Checked)
            {
                str += GridView1.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString() + ',';
                strname += gvrow.Cells[8].Text + ',';

            }
        }
        strname = strname.Trim(",".ToCharArray());
        lblRecord.Text = "<b>Credit Request: </b>" + strname;
    }
```

tried to debug it. its not getting the cell value at all. what am i missing here?

[updated output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI6TL.jpg)

UPDATE!:

Manged to make it work. its the masterpage cause why its not working. here is my code:

```
protected void btmDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string data = "";
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkCtrl") as CheckBox);
                if (chkRow.Checked)
                {
                    using (SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True"))
                    {
                        scn.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE UserData SET CreditRequest = CAST(REPLACE(c.CreditRequest, ',', '') as int) FROM CreditRequests c INNER JOIN Userdata u on c.username=u.username Where c.Username=@Username", scn);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Session["New"];

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        lblmsg.Text = "Approved";
```

What i want to happen now is when the checkbox is clicked, that row(specifically row8) will be updated on my sql database. i have tried the code above but its giving me an error:

The parameterized query '(@Username nvarchar(4000))UPDATE UserData SET CreditRequest = CA' expects the parameter '@Username', which was not supplied.

debug update:

[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1Dk5.jpg)

UPDATE 2:

i tried having this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update UserData set CreditRequest = '" + row.Cells[8].Text + "' where Username=@Username", scn);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = row.Cells[1].Text;
```

and my error is 
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '5,000

Comment: Try `gvrow.Cells[8].Value`

Comment: @MairajAhmad error occured. missing an assembly reference sir

Comment: also, value is not in the option list sir

Comment: are you check your indexing 7 or 8?

Comment: i want to show the value of cell 8 @shamimreza

Comment: @shamimreza tried to debug it, strname has no value. its not checking the  if statement. it proceeds to the label

Comment: @MairajAhmad please help me out sir

Comment: @shamimreza need your help sir

Comment: Can u please share the screen ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad updated output shown sir

Comment: same output sir. no value is shown. its not performing the `checkbox chk` line sir.

Comment: Is checkbox proeperty autopostback set to true ?

Comment: just set it to true sir

Comment: @MairajAhmad its even worse when i set it to true. when i click on the checbox, it removes the gridview and shows the label only. i didnt even click the button sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are binding the `gridview` on `Page_Load` make sure you have set     `if(!IsPostBack)`

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
//BindGridView here
}
```

Try this

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Session["New"].ToString());
```

UPdate

Remove single qoutes around the value of CreditRequest

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update UserData set CreditRequest = " + row.Cells[8].Text + " where Username=@Username", scn);
```

Comment: error sir. Object reference not set to an instance of an object. `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Session["New"].ToString());`

Comment: sir it should be `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Session["New"];`

Comment: because im updating a specific row from this gdview to a table in my database. and it will update it based on username

Comment: It doesn't make any difference your session is null that's why you are getting this exception.

Comment: hmm because this is my past working code (w/o checkbox), but now it has checkbox to choose from, it gives me an error. can you help me out on the sql statement?

Comment: what i want is to update `userdata table`, `creditrequest column` with the credit request row in this gridview? (but of course on the selected item)

Comment: UPdate userdata set creditrequest = row.Cells[8].Text where username=@username

Comment: thank you. but has an error `Incorrect syntax near '8'.`

Comment: `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update UserData set CreditRequests = row.Cells[8].Text where Username=@Username",scn);`

Comment: debug and check what sql is generated

Comment: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update UserData set CreditRequests = '"+row.Cells[8].Text+"' where Username=@Username",scn);

Comment: You need to concatenate the value of cell[8]

Comment: how to do that sir pls

Comment: `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update UserData set CreditRequests = '"+row.Cells[8].Text+"' where Username=@Username",scn);`

Comment: same error sirrr `The parameterized query '(@Username nvarchar(4000))Update UserData set CreditRequests = '' expects the parameter '@Username', which was not supplied.`

Comment: lets try to remove the session sir

Comment: Remove single qoutes around `Cells[8].Text`

Comment: PLease conside marking as answer if it was helpful.

Comment: of course! thank you for all of your help. you stayed. hehe thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

use it

foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox chkrow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkrow") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox);
                if (chkrow.Checked)
                {
                   strname = GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
                }
            }
        }